# RDLC Edit Existing Dataset is blank Visual Studio 2013

Tags: dataset, rdlc

Hi I was wondering if someone could help, after having to replace my hard disk and re-installing windows and vs 2013. I can get my project working which is great.  However when I try to edit an existing rdlc datset it is blank? this is also the case if I create a new dataset on the report, it doesn't even store the name I type it just states Dataset1

I have tried rebuilding and cleaning the solution but to no avail

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the RDLC Designer or the ReportViewer ? Or the actual Dataset, as in a DataTable for example? A screenshot will definitely be required. It's unclear what exactly is the problem, let alone what could be causing the issue.

Comment: Hi there, i did initially include a screenshot but hasnt appeared for some reason! This was editing the dataset via the rdlc designer.  I have since fixed this by re-installing windows again, then installing vs 2010 then vs2013! So fingers crossed it keeps behaving but thanks for your reply!